# Neural Networks output range in simulation

Tags: neural-networks, python, nonlinear-regression

I am learning some model based on examples ${((x_{i1},x_{i2},....,x_{ip}),y_i)}_{i=1...N}$ using a neural network of Feed Forward Multilayer Perceptron (newff) (using python library neurolab). I expect the output of the NN to be positive for any further simulation of the NN. 
How can I make sure that the results of simulation (testing) of my learned NN are always positive? 
(how I do it in neurolab?)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to be, to use a Log sigmoid in the output neuron of the model will guaranty a positive output.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can think of the unbounded output as the logarithm of the positive value, which is equal to using `exp(output)` as the activation function.